# Returning web results page

Tags: python, web, request, urllib2

Okay, I have narrowed down my problem of returning google search results with python.  It's NOT an issue of the search or using API.  It's an issue of HOW TO READ THE RESULTS WITH PYTHON.

Now, please someone, anyone, show me the code that would simply print the result of the webpage just as a browser would (the words, and text, I don't even care if it has all the html script.. as long as it does contain the text from the web page, and the urls... )

So, here's the url I'm trying to load a results page into python from:

```
    https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiv5l6a7Y6F6PDOH62elkfPDoGserB70if-j-hUzcB30VB0IOmADts8UKGKr8dRpfXlU3VVMA-TOTbqYHXl4weH3A9fyYrpubR8zXlxSR_1jvfMbrz3nkeHCxTYgoSR34KQmSGYlV6NTXP1ag7QumbRdKqqlWsg6RwZh-v0ogPxPqEn3a_1dWgX_1SisyEKKRAD6K-Zge6NA-i54t0-sNR0lINQ96d_1YfN9aw7KQlZp2bzcw97h8Ckb1XR0-t9B_1WbdTv1A1WDWttcfUMGI3Y5zIgwHoQPpNM6x9zbhgemlabzqbMJzGUezF3KT1KG6AWCRdnlaMWbMb_1m_1T-A_1EHnqDm0Wt3wILSIAHdi_1sfMjSyDN2wNjeFxJ3LsGAZN-sx24MIlOz7nT4wOmXtEeECRIBvuSS4iH7SbeC5gf3Iac41He1k7w_1NTt1_1-R8TsdryCxs0Pysu2DA7WuBMLqHcrovkgoCZLGdXbuWx_1nY4nu39VqBiBIpQOPMfPkTknT_1M0nVgO_1ppmSgikY3fKbIByzz8FOJgUBb0Nu2p_1Zoo-XRprDgOb-UVubVk-CsGwN2dF_1I81J6vFOUI_14bS5nYjZaEHx6-Lxxij84Za-fL5G4XCnZc-0LPyzAmbvckao55OXqMUBgZbx9e7VRg2jLYaxrzFYtiIUqjG9-IqXoi4ZhWTxZuk_1sUkXFO3NNdeuQ_1Ise9lisoBCLyfpBz1Qnh1dvP_1zb0Cor2Vbp9gTr9VjuOxTHjglWJSntw4OLt6jCfdZOve-iuEdh9V5fSPk41WidEfkWTxMo1dfbPxShrGFGF1oEdd6soYCJnp6YjnXYEYGOEMUgdBUXdB1bFbmBop5WUUizhfgiOyTmGMPEyv7FH3MeiQCTf2pab6v1OdE7lRcKbHqQ3_1jcWi0IUTlk3UGnNSdWjS80h_1N4ljbWJ7CTT7RtJKDoL73rk0bKNgtGz5WeChnZ11AOQJEgV6hb9eyw56qIY37nNom3ehQhTuz5bvWtg1tKjySP1ezRU7TS_1ijJWK6m9ke9LkRXqbUVxZaCy0L6nAzIYh0ODOaZBexsCeLXV4N8iCxetcjmpBU7TvsoD319lRUcU-dfPEn4UfEAQTcP7x3WLHa1k5EOAXsYcXyWxk7N5GqcuPYmrYWvh_1V1hXjlcKCArh699NyyPCfaNpYlyS0IHRCz8VmVSXi07MxH9apW_1bFDK-h-zcy0_1qfH6uJoo_1BXp_1C0C8EM11UvczLZyKgX4LeFA7X0jJ57n6rr4Zysd2kEhrhJp6hJDSmkLcsF5UOsJ2i4MotSxrUB-tc5s9teV13Xr2-3f7wTbEqylWnYgwil1bA_10HKWMclDvhWJqsGQRFLu9_1lB-7gIwV0kS8xEfA
```

And here is the webpage searched through www.hidemyass.com (proxy web searcher):

```
    http://5.hidemyass.com/ip-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%3D%3D&f=norefer
```

So it is clearly evident that python CAN return search results of this page, I just cant' figure it out.

Now, I am new, so I am learning, but so far the only responses from people I get are that I should use the google API, or that I should use non-python methods (including spynner or selenium, which are not the standard python libraries..)  Surely someone on here knows how to do this.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
    import urllib2

    req=urllib2.Request(link)
    response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page=response.read()
    print(page)

    #or thru hidemyass.com:

    req=urllib2.Request('http://hidemyass.com/',link)
    response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page=response.read()
    print(page)

    # BeautifulSoup :

    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

    soup=BeautifulSoup(page)
    print(soup)
```

None of it works:(  I don't get the results page, I don't get the "Best guess for this image" text.. I get a mess:(

Comment: I tried your first block of code (up to line 5). Then called python test.py > test.html. Then I loaded this with my browser, and got the google search page. Not a mess. Not the actual search results you want either though.

Comment: So, I loaded the original link in firefox directly, and it showed your Toyota Camry search. Then I loaded the Firebug tool, went to the Net panel, and reloaded the page.... it shows quite a few different GET's occuring.

Comment: See where I'm going with this? :-)  Obviously urllib2 doesn't process the javascripty ajaxy stuff that's going on (just check out test.html and search for Request). That's why other people who know what they're talking about are pointing you to the Google API etc.

Comment: okay so python can't interact with modern web then, using it's built in libraries?  that's terrible.  Actually it's unbelievable.  I know I will figure this out in time, I'm very determined:):):) I'm just sad that nobody can help me, as I've been only studying python a few months and already I'm having to be answering my own questions without help...  :(